# Can runtime package parameters for child packages be retrieved from SSISDB?

Tags: ssis, etl

Is there a way to retrieve the run-time package parameters used from an execution of a child package?

Deployment model is SSIDB (SQL 2017).  These child packages run from a master package (ExecutePackage tasks), with values passed from the master to the child package's parameters.

I know that child packages don't get their own row in SSISDB.catalog.executions: you have to search for the master package's row.  Then, in SSISDB.catalog.event_messages, you can filter on package_name to find the messages generated by the child package.

I had hopes about SSISDB.catalog.execution_parameter_values - but that only shows parameters (project- and package-level) for the *master* package.

I tried looking in event_messages for the child package - but there's no message about runtime parameter values.  Then in event_message for the ExecutePackage task which calls the child package: again, nothing about parameter values.

Am I on a hiding to nothing here?

**Context**

I'm trying to work around a poorly-designed ETL process, whereby a controller package calls various master packages, but calls them *by running SQL jobs*.  There's therefore no (non-kludgy) way for the controller package to create an overall log record, retrieve its PK ID, and pass it on to all packages involved (master and child) so that they can "know" which overall ETL run they're running under.

In particular, because this controller package launches the last tranche of master packages (through jobs) and then exits, there is no appropriate time at which to mark the overall process "closed/done".  I was hoping that detecting non-complete executions in which this process ID exists as a parameter value would provide a way to do this.

Comment: Is there no way to change the controller package to call the master packages with execute package tasks instead?  Or is there some purpose behind using sql agent jobs?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that would solve the problem.  There is a purpose to using jobs: ExecutePackage is restricted to packages within the same project.  With c.750 packages overall, they'd all have to be in one project.  I've found even with c.150 packages, VS runs into horrific build problems.
I have to work around the existing controller architecture at the moment.  Longer term, something like Tim Mitchell's refinement of catalog.createexecution (https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/11/28/a-better-way-to-execute-ssis-packages-with-t-sql/) is probably the way to do it.

Comment: Is the real question "How can I tell when the whole thing is done"?  If so, the execution logs should help here.  Also, that's a lot of packages -- if they are generally executing a single data flow, there's an opportunity there to consolidate related work into single packages.  Maybe you can also relay if there are reasons for this approach.